# Conservation of energy during the flight of a fire cracker

Tags: energy-conservation, rocket-science, combustion

We say that energy is neither created or destroyed. It can only be transformed. I hope this principle is applied in the flight of a fire cracker. The chemical energy is converted into physical energy and so the rocket flies up. But basically how is it transformed?

Comment: *I hope...* I think *hope* is a bit ambiguous. I propose you to cite a reference or add an explanation of why you think so.

Comment: It's called [combustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion).

Answer (score 1):

The particles that constitute the flammable material in fire cracker gets agitated wildly when sufficient heat is supplied. They (salts of sodium, sulfur etc) combine with oxygen releasing heat which causes the other particles to agitate and combine with oxygen and so on thus creating a chain reaction. The left over energy released as heat during the chemical reaction will cause the fragments to fly in all directions thus creating an explosion. Well, the flight of a rocket can be understood in terms of conservation of momentum along with with energy. The particles goes of from the exhaust carries some momentum with them which in turn led the rocket to move in the opposite direction to conserve the total momentum of the system. Now here the energy released during burning of the fuel cause both the fragments as well as the rocket (bigger fragment!) to move.